# I faced the "Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path" while place order in checkout page?

Tags: magento2

please help to fix these issues

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path

Exception #0 (LogicException): Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path

```
#1 Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Interceptor->getQuote() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php:221]
#2 Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart->getQuote() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart/Interceptor.php:76]
#3 Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor->getQuote() called at [app/code/StripeIntegration/Payments/Helper/Generic.php:439]
#4 StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Generic->hasSubscriptions() called at [app/code/StripeIntegration/Payments/Plugin/Tax/Config.php:22]
#5 StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Tax\Config->aroundGetAlgorithm() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#6 Magento\Tax\Model\Config\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#7 Magento\Tax\Model\Config\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Tax/Model/Config/Interceptor.php:130]
#8 Magento\Tax\Model\Config\Interceptor->getAlgorithm() called at [vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/TaxCalculation.php:163]
#9 Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation->calculateTax() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#10 Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#11 Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#12 call_user_func_array() called at [vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/Plugin/TaxCalculationPlugin.php:69]
#13 Vertex\Tax\Model\Plugin\TaxCalculationPlugin->aroundCalculateTax() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#14 Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Tax/Model/TaxCalculation/Interceptor.php:26]
#16 Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation\Interceptor->calculateTax() called at [vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php:43]
#17 Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal->collect() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#18 Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#19 Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#20 call_user_func_array() called at [vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/Plugin/SubtotalPlugin.php:64]
#21 Vertex\Tax\Model\Plugin\SubtotalPlugin->aroundCollect() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#22 Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal/Interceptor.php:26]
#24 Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal\Interceptor->collect() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php:274]
#25 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collectAddressTotals() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php:148]
#26 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collect() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php:1995]
#27 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote->collectTotals() called at [generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Interceptor.php:1064]
#28 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor->collectTotals() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php:269]
#29 Magento\Checkout\Model\Session->getQuote() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session/Interceptor.php:63]
#30 Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Interceptor->getQuote() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage.php:153]
#31 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#32 Mageplaza\Osc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#33 Mageplaza\Osc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#34 Mageplaza\Osc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Mageplaza/Osc/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:91]
#35 Mageplaza\Osc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#40 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#42 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#43 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#45 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#46 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#47 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#48 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: can you remove generated and run di compile command do paste errors here for compile command

Comment: thanks for helping its working now stripe payment module version problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes some time when we use any custom payment gateway with checkout page.
Please disable custom/paid payment gateway first if you are using then try to create order.

Then debug with that specific payment gateway extensions.

Thank you.

Comment: thanks for helping its working now stripe payment module version problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use checkoutSession->getQuote()!!! it will cause infinite loop for quotes with trigger_recollect = 1, see Quote::_afterLoad() in custom shipping module development.

Alternative you can load a quote like

```
$isQuoteExists = true;

    $items = $subject->getAllItems();
    if (!empty($items)) {
        $firstItem = reset($items);
        if ($firstItem) {
            $quote = $firstItem->getQuote();
            if (!($quote instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote)) {
                $isQuoteExists = false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $isQuoteExists = false;
    }
```

You can run your logic remaining logic if $isQuoteExist true or false based on your requirements.

Let me know if you need more help who are facing such issue.

Thanks, Sam